# adding arrayList to arraylist using loop

Tags: java, arraylist

Whenever i try and run my code i get an error array out of bounds.

```
    trans = new ArrayList<List<Transition>>(5);
    ArrayList<Transition> t = new ArrayList<Transition>(5);
    for (j = 0; j <5; j++)
        trans.get(j).addAll(t); // <- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Comment: The *capacity* of a list is **not** its size. Your list is actually empty, and that's why you get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: use `trans.add(t)` or `trans.add(j,t)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an empty list of size 0 when you create your list of lists and then you say get(i) which will try to compare size with i and jdk expect size to be greater than the index i.

So probably you could do something like:

```
trans = new ArrayList<List<Transition>>(5);
for (j = 0; j <5; j++) {
   trans.add(new ArrayList<Transition>()); 
}
ArrayList<Transition> t = new ArrayList<Transition>(5);
for (j = 0; j <5; j++)
    trans.get(j).addAll(t); // <- out of bounds
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `trans` list is empty. You didn't `add` anything to it. When you run  `trans.get(j)` it can't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

See the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-):

> Constructs an **empty** list with the specified initial capacity.

You didn't `add` anything, you cannot `get`:

```
 trans.get(j).addAll(t);
       ↑
```

Try to check the size, you'll get 0. So any attempt to access the `trans` will *throw* an exception.